# Default argument and variable-length argument in python

Tags: python

In function I've defined two arguments `1:default` variable say `age=12` and `2:variable-length` argument say `*friends`

```
    def variable(age=12,*friends):
         print 'Age:', age
         print 'Name:', friends
         return
    variable(15,'amit','rishabh') # RESULT is "Age: 15 & Name: 'amit', 'rishabh'
    variable('rahul','sourabh') # Now here result is Age: rahul & Name: 'sourabh'
```

so my question is why function does'nt take both this arguments in `*friends` variable why it determine the first argument as age.

I need result should be in this format as:

```
variable(15,'name','surname') as Age:15 and Name: 'name','surname'
```

and if I don't assign age as

```
variable('new','name') Result needed to be as. Age:12 & Name:'new','name'
```

Comment: "why it determine the first argument as age." because that's how you defined your function.

Comment: how is your program supposed to know if the first argument is an age or a name? Maybe check for `type` if that's the behavior you are after...

Comment: The first argument will always be considered to be the age since you constructed your function this way.

Comment: try to pass a list for friends.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to give in a list instead of various arguments, also keyword arguments should always go after aguments:

```
def variable(friends, age=12):
    print 'Age:', age
    print 'Name:', ",".join(friends)
    return
variable(['amit','rishabh'], 15) # RESULT is "Age: 15 & Name: 'amit', 'rishabh'
variable(['rahul','sourabh']) # Now here result is Age: rahul & Name: 'sourabh'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try switching the arguments:

```
def variable(*friends,age=12):
    print ('Age:', age)
    print ('Name:', friends)
    return
```

This should work.

Comment: This won't work, as if you given `*args`,`**kwargs` must follow, explicit arguments must come before, `(name, age=12, *args, **kwargs)` this is the correct syntax

Comment: You are correct that this may not follow the correct syntax. Nevertheless it does work. The OP should accept your answer though!

Comment: Are you sure? I'm trying it on Python 2.7 and my IDE is telling me `Encountered "age" at line 268, column 23. Was expecting one of:     "*" ...     "**" ...`

Comment: Also running the code is giving me a Syntax Exception, might be working on Python 3?

Comment: Yes, I am running python 3.6.6 and tested it in a jupyter notebook.